# How to do LOESS smoothing in R?

Tags: r, loess

I have a simple list of Y values over time.  I do not have X values, but could supply 1, 2, 3, ... if needed.  I want to do LOESS smoothing using the loess() function.  What is the correct way to do this?

This is what I am doing right now (where 405 is the number of items in y):

```
loess(1:405~y, span=0.25)
```

Questions/issues so far:

- It is ignoring my span parameter completely; supplying different values gives the same results
- I do not understand R well enough to know what 1:405~y actually means
- What is the format of the output?  How do I get the time series of the loess plotted Y values out?

Comment: Sounds like you need to start from the help page: `?loess`. I would put `x` and `y` into a data frame _e.g._ `mydata`, then use `loess(y ~ x, data = mydata, span = 0.25)`.

Comment: @neilfws Thanks - How would I put c(100, 121, ...) into a dataframe?  (Sorry for basic questions)

Comment: If you already have a vector `y` then `mydata <- data.frame(y = y, x = 1:405)` will do it.

Comment: @neilfws this worked - thank you!